# How can I monitor HTTP traffic in C?

Tags: c, http

I'm writing a program similar to fiddler or wireshark (but on a more simpler scale), and I was wondering how you would go about monitoring the HTTP request and response in C.

My initial guess was to create an infinite loop a new thread and monitor it at the TCP level. Maybe I'm wrong.

Any advice on best practices for doing something like the above?

Comment: You can't do this using just C and the standard C library, it would help if you could tell us what OS you're using.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 but also require it to work on XP and Vista. I don't mind using libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by getting familiar with the [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library, or `libpcap` for most other OS'es - this allows you to capture packets quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WinPcap/libpcap for capturing packets on IP level, but if you need to track TCP/IP session, it's better to use [libnids](http://libnids.sourceforge.net/) which allow you to operate on sessions instead of packets.